# No Matching Function Call

Tags: c++, constructor

I'm new to C++ and trying to code a HashTable data structure.
I've written it to be generic using templates, and I've included a HashEntry object to use in it to allow for easy quadratic probing for collisions. 
The code I have is:

(in a .C file that #include's the below class definition .H file):

```
   HashEntry::HashEntry()
   {
      this->isActive = false;
   }
```

And the associated .H file with the class definitions is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Entry.C" 
using namespace std;

#define Default_Size 50000

class HashEntry;

template <class T> class HashTable
{
private:
  int size;
  int occupied;
  T array[Default_Size];

public:
  HashTable();
  int Size();
  void Add(T t);
  void DebugAdd(T t, int index);
  T* Get(string index);
  /* How do I declare the existence of HashEntry BEFORE here? */
  int FindNextOpen(HashEntry he); // Only works for hash_entry objects!
  int Hash(string str);
  void Rehash();
};

class HashEntry
{
private:
  Entry e;
  bool isActive;

public:
  HashEntry();
  HashEntry(Entry e);
  bool IsActive();
  Entry GetEntry();
};
```

Whenever I try and compile everything, I get the error for the HashEntry constructor above:
"no matching function for call to Entry::Entry()" ... "candidates are.....".
I have no idea what it means -- when I try to include a default Entry() constructor (my first interpretation), it throws more errors.

Thanks for the help!

UPDATE -- ENTRY.C:

```
#include "Entry.H"
/* ***Entry Methods*** */
/*
 * Overloaded Entry obejct constructor that provides a string value.
 */
Entry::Entry(string s)
{
  this->value = s;
  this->count = 0;
}

/*
 * Returns the number of times this Entry has been accessed/
 * found.
 */
int Entry::Count()
{ return this->count; }

/*
 * Returns the string value stored in the Entry object.
 */
string Entry::Value()
{ return this->value; }
```

Comment: Can you show us the contents of Entry.C?

Comment: The problem seems to be in the Entry.C file. Could you provide the source for that?

Comment: You're programming in C++ but your files have a `.c` extension? It really should have a `.cpp` extension, since `.c` usually means a C source file. Some compilers will actually change their compilation mode depending on the file extension.

Comment: @Insilico `.C` (as opposed to `.c`) is sometimes used for C++. On a case-insensitive filesystem that might possibly cause problems, but that seems unlikely here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.
The error message says there is not matching function call for "Entry::Entry()". Because in no case was I actually creating Entry objects I had no idea what it meant.
I tried adding an explicit default constructor for class Entry and it resolved.

Thanks for the help everyone!

Comment: Re "Because in no case was I actually creating Entry objects": Sure you are. Your class `HashEntry` has a data member `e` that is an `Entry`. Every time you create a `HashEntry` you create an `Entry`.

Answer (score 4):

> And the associated .H file with the class definitions is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Entry.C"
```

Whoa! Never, ever #include a source file in a header.

Your Entry.C should not exist. Instead define the constructor in your header, inside the class definition:

```
class HashEntry
{
private:
  Entry e;
  bool isActive;

public:
  HashEntry() : isActive(true) {}
...
}
```

One thing that you haven't shown us is the definition of the class `Entry`. That is one of the sources of your problem. It's a bit hard to pin down your problem when you didn't show us the very thing that is causing it.

Comment: That's a really good point.
I've edited my original post to contain the source for Entry.C.